# django queryset cannot run function inside annotate and Sum

Tags: python, django, type-conversion, django-queryset

I have two queryset and I want to do Addition from those two queryset but one query value are Int type (e.g. 1.5, 2.75 ) but others have time like string (e.g. 12:20:59). I need to convert that string to Int type so I can do use Sum Function in Annotate.

First queryset

```
timesheet_total_by_project = TimesheetEntry.objects.filter(
    created_by_id=current_user,
    timesheet__for_date__gte=start_tim,
    timesheet__for_date__lte=end_date,
    project__is_visible=True
).values(
    'project__name', 'project__id'
).distinct().annotate(totalsum=Sum('minutes', output_field=FloatField()) / 60.0)
```

2nd Queryset

```
ticket_total_time = Ticket.objects.filter(
     assigned_to=user, total_time__isnull=False, project__is_visible=True
).values(
    'title','project__id'
).distinct().annotate(totalsum=Sum('total_time', output_field=FloatField()) / 60.0)
```

I have tried

```
def get_sec(time_str):
        print("string",time_str)
        """Get Seconds from time."""
        h, m, s = time_str.split(':')
        return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)
```

```
ticket_total_time = Ticket.objects.filter(assigned_to=user,total_time__isnull=False,project__is_visible=True).values('title','project__id').distinct().annotate(totalsum=Sum(get_sec('total_time'), output_field=FloatField()) / 3600.0)
```

Expected Output is would be 12.5
but output for  print("string",time_str)

```
string total_time
```

Also says

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Comment: This isn't a thing that makes sense. An annotate function is translated to SQL and applied in the database; you can't pass an arbitrary Python function there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I understood that. But as I wanted to convert that "Time" like string type value into Integer,  Is there any way that I can convert that value to Integer so I can perform Sum inside annotate?

Comment: Are you sure it's a string and not a time? Show the models.

Comment: `
starting_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True) 
finishing_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
total_time = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
`

Comment: That's weird, why is it a TextField?

Comment: And what database are you using?

Comment: That is from existing project :( .  I am just started working on this project.
 Mysql Database is using in this project.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function that will convert a string to a date. You can run arbitrary database functions with a [`Func` expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value

ticket_total_time = Ticket.objects.filter(
     assigned_to=user, total_time__isnull=False, project__is_visible=True
).values(
    'title','project__id'
).distinct().
annotate(time_t=Func(F('total_time'), Value('%H:%i:%s'), function='STR_TO_DATE')).
annotate(totalsum=Sum('time_t', output_field=FloatField()) / 60.0)
```

Comment: ```
    class Time_to_sec(Func):
        function = 'TIME_TO_SEC'
        lookup_name = 'sec'
```

I use this function and run this function inside annotate Sum. Now I get the Seconds. Thank you @Denial

Comment: Above solution was not worked for me but I have got the idea from your solution and I solved that using other way.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_sec(time_str):
    print(f'{time_str = }')
    """Get Seconds from time."""
    if not time_str:
        return 0
    h, m, s = time_str.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + int(s)
```

Comment: that function is working but when I tried to use inside annotate like 
```.annotate(totalsum=Sum(get_sec('total_time'), output_field=FloatField()) / 3600.0)```
then it's not working. That time it get exact string 'total_time' instead of database value.

Comment: use `aggregate` instead of `annotate`

Answer (score 0):

I tried this solution and it work fine. Now Time_to_sec function is working inside annotate.

```
from django.db.models import F, Func

class Time_to_sec(Func):
           function = 'TIME_TO_SEC'
           lookup_name = 'sec'

ticket_total_time = Ticket.objects.filter(assigned_to=user,total_time__isnull=False,project__is_visible=True).values('project__id').distinct().annotate(totalsum=Sum(Time_to_sec('total_time', output_field=FloatField()) / 3600.0))
```